Identify smd component ( p_j89 ck)
I have electronic board of level switch device. I have a problem in it a found an element it seems like a diode but I need its data sheet to find a replacement for it  because it is short circuit
in the circuit it connecting between power input +24 V and 0.
This devices is FTL 320 produced approximately in 1998.




Dimensions is nearly 5*3 mm





that looks like a fuse

Likely it would help if you would sketch out a schematic and place the unknown component into it so we might have a better idea of where to start looking. As it is, it is difficult to guess at what even the part number is.  For instance 89 might be a date code. Is this from something that might have been made 30 to 35 years ago?

Please provide dimensions

Dimension is  5mm * 3 mm

Device is FTL 320  produced approximately in 1998  i make edit in the topic and added extra photos

It's probably a Panjit P6SMBJ30CA TVS diode.


The markings look a bit different on current Panjit diodes,

(Source: lcsc.com)
but I found this picture of a different Panjit diode that shows a four character tracability code like on the part in question.

(Source: rapidonline.com)
This makes me think that the markings changed a bit over time.
